# facing errors while saving my apex class

Tags: apex

```
public with sharing class CTPeopleTracingController {
    public static  list<People_Tracing__c> getTraces(string personId){
        return [SELECT Id, Contact_Date__c, Person_1__c, Person_1__r.Health_Status__c, Person_1__r.Token__c, Person_2__c,
        Person_2__r.Health_Status__c, Person_2__r.Token__c 
        FROM  People_Tracing__c
        WHERE Person_1__c=:personId 
        OR Person_2__c=:personId 
        ORDER BY Contact_Date__c DESC];
    }
    public static list<People_Tracing__c> checkDuplicates(list<People_Tracing__c> newPeopleTraces){
        //stroe all the unique ids 
        set<Id> personIds = new set<Id>();
        for(People_Tracing__c trace : newPeopleTraces){
            personIds.add(trace.Person_1__c);
            personIds.add(trace.Person_2__c);
        }
    // list duplicate records
    list<People_Tracing__c> duplicates = new list<People_Tracing__c>();
    //map id and set <Id>
    map<Id, set<Id>> mapOfExsitingRecords = new map<Id, set<Id>> ();
    
    // query existing records
    list<People_Tracing__c> exsitingRecords = [SELECT Id, Person_1__c,Person_2__c 
    FROM People_Tracing__c
    WHERE Person_1__c=:personId 
    OR Person_2__c=:personId];

    if(existingRecords != null && existingRecords.size()>0)
    for(People_Tracing__c trace : existingRecords){
    if(! mapOfExsitingRecords.containsKey(trace.Person_1__c)){
        mapOfExsitingRecords.put(trace.Person_1__c, new set<Id>());
    }
    mapOfExsitingRecords.get(trace.Person_1__c).add(trace.Person_2__c);
    }
    // build map for person 2
    if(mapOfExsitingRecords.containsKey(trace.Person_2__c)){
        mapOfExsitingRecords.put(trace.Person_2__c,new set<Id>());
    }
    mapOfExsitingRecords.get(trace.Person_2__c).add(trace.Person_1__c);
    }

    // loop over existing records to find duplicates
    for(People_Tracing__c trace : newPeopleTraces){

        // chcek for duplicates in map
        if(mapOfExsitingRecords.containsKey(trace.Person_1__c) 
        && mapOfExsitingRecords.get(trace.Person_1__c).contains(trace.Person_2__c)) 
        ||
        if(mapOfExsitingRecords.containsKey(trace.Person_2__c) 
        && mapOfExsitingRecords.get(trace.Person_2__c).contains(trace.Person_1__c));{
            duplicate.add(tarce);
        }

    }
    }
    return duplicates;
    }

}
```

this is my class

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There was many places where you mis-spelt the variable names. And even the flower braces were not kept at correct places as well. I have modified all the variable and places the braces in correct places. Can you check the below code.

```
public with sharing class CTPeopleTracingController {
    public static  list<People_Tracing__c> getTraces(string personId){
        return [SELECT Id, Contact_Date__c, Person_1__c, Person_1__r.Health_Status__c, Person_1__r.Token__c, Person_2__c,
        Person_2__r.Health_Status__c, Person_2__r.Token__c 
        FROM  People_Tracing__c
        WHERE Person_1__c=:personId 
        OR Person_2__c=:personId 
        ORDER BY Contact_Date__c DESC];
    }
    public static list<People_Tracing__c> checkDuplicates(list<People_Tracing__c> newPeopleTraces){
        //stroe all the unique ids 
        set<Id> personIds = new set<Id>();
        for(People_Tracing__c trace : newPeopleTraces){
            personIds.add(trace.Person_1__c);
            personIds.add(trace.Person_2__c);
        }
    // list duplicate records
    list<People_Tracing__c> duplicates = new list<People_Tracing__c>();
    //map id and set <Id>
    map<Id, set<Id>> mapOfExsitingRecords = new map<Id, set<Id>> ();
    
    // query existing records
    list<People_Tracing__c> existingRecords = [SELECT Id, Person_1__c,Person_2__c 
    FROM People_Tracing__c
    WHERE Person_1__c=:personIds 
    OR Person_2__c=:personIds];

    if(existingRecords != null && existingRecords.size()>0)
    for(People_Tracing__c traces : existingRecords){
    if(! mapOfExsitingRecords.containsKey(traces.Person_1__c)){
        mapOfExsitingRecords.put(traces.Person_1__c, new set<Id>());
    }
    mapOfExsitingRecords.get(traces.Person_1__c).add(traces.Person_2__c);
    
    // build map for person 2
    if(mapOfExsitingRecords.containsKey(traces.Person_2__c)){
        mapOfExsitingRecords.put(traces.Person_2__c,new set<Id>());
    }
    mapOfExsitingRecords.get(traces.Person_2__c).add(traces.Person_1__c);
    
    }
    // loop over existing records to find duplicates
    for(People_Tracing__c tarce : newPeopleTraces){

        // chcek for duplicates in map
        if((mapOfExsitingRecords.containsKey(tarce.Person_1__c) 
        && mapOfExsitingRecords.get(tarce.Person_1__c).contains(tarce.Person_2__c)) ||
        (mapOfExsitingRecords.containsKey(tarce.Person_2__c) 
        && mapOfExsitingRecords.get(tarce.Person_2__c).contains(tarce.Person_1__c))){
            duplicates.add(tarce);
        }

    }
    
    return duplicates;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, Sai Praveen this is really helpful, I was trying for the last 3-4 days but couldn't find any mistakes in my answer but you did it like a pro.